# Google Datastudio - Extract Values from Comma separated String

Tags: looker-studio

I have a Sheet in which i import daily a CSV of reporting containing a column which contains comma separated values containing locations and a value

| Item ID | Location results |
| --- | --- |
| 112 | Location A :1;Location B:3;Location C:4;Location D:1 |
| 113 | Location A :5;Location F:1;Location X:9;Location Z:1 |
| 116 | Location AA:3 |

I need to generate report in google datastudio that looks like showing the value after the : of that specific location. And i don't want to make too many manual changes every time to every sheet in Gsheets, so i hope that datastudio formula can solve this for me.

Another issue is that the Location names need to be an exact match as some names contain similar words like "Brussels North", "Brussels", "Antwerp North"

The news item ID is unique for each row

Any idea how i can get this data in datastudio?

Thank you
Tom

In Excel i got this to work via =IFNA(VLOOKUP($D$2:$D$7,TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(INDEX($B$2:$B$100,MATCH(E1,$A$2:$A$100,0)),":",";")),2,0),"")

I would need a view like this

Results view

| Location | 112 | 113 | 116 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Location A | 1 | 5 | 0 |
| Location B | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Location AA | 0 | 0 | 3 |

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

- as shown in the screenshot you can paste the raw csv import data in columns A, B
- the arrayformula in D2 arranges the data that's compatible with the expected output in data studio

D2 formula:

`=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:A&"|"&BYROW(B2:B,LAMBDA(hx,SPLIT(JOIN("",BYCOL(SPLIT(hx,";"),LAMBDA(ax,REPT(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(ax,"(.*):.*$"))&"|",--REGEXEXTRACT(ax,":(\d+)$"))))),"|")))),"|",0,0)),"Select * Where Col2!=''")`

- Connect columns D, E to data studio

### Create pivot table with

```
Location as Row dimension

Item ID as column dimension

Item ID in metric with COUNT as aggregation
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems to work but only in fairly small datasets, the moment it goes above 20-25 items Google sheets keeps crashing on it

Comment: I have tested multiple cases and it seems to crash on cells where there are a lot of options in 1 cell. I have tried to break it up in pieces as i thought it would be.a special character or something in the text breaking the formula, but when i seperate them in blocks it works